# Evaluate CloudFormation functions like !Sub, !Ref or !Import before deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to inspect what a CloudFormation function such as Fn::Sub would resolve / evaluate to before a stack is deployed?

For example, if I have something like this:

```
Parameters:
  ParameterStorePrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: The names of parameters for this service start with this

Resources:
  SomeResource:
    ...
    Secrets:
      - Name: SECRET_PARAMETER_FROM_PARAMETER_STORE
        ValueFrom: !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/${ParameterStorePrefix}/asecret"
```

There are a few things happening here, including a parameter that would be passed with `--parameters-file` and special AWS variables / pseudo-parameters. In another template things might be more complicated still. CloudFormation does this for me at some point. When?

After SomeResource is deployed, it knows to get this parameter from `"arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:123456789:parameter/my/parameterstore/path/asecret"`. This is visible in the web console, and accessible with aws cli; in this case I have a batch Job Definition so I can do

```
$ aws batch describe-job-definitions
{
"jobDefinitions": [
  ...
  "containerProperties": {
    ...
    "secrets": [
        {
            "name": "SECRET_PARAMETER_FROM_PARAMETER_STORE",
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:123456789:parameter/my/parameterstore/path/asecret"
        }
```

Is there any way to get to this representation before I deploy? CloudFormation must be preparing it somewhere in the background in order to stop me or roll-back if I'm defining the parameter incorrectly.

I've tried looking through what's provided by [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint), but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. It seems to be making heavy use of parsing the templates.

I would like to be able to do this for a template even before its stack's first deployment, so I can't think of a way to use a change-set.

Comment: No that's not possible. The intrinsic functions are only used at runtime